# Writing to file in Python using multiple processes

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, multiprocessing, critical-section

I have been exploring multiprocessor programming in python and the differences it has with multithreading and the doubt I had was regarding writing to a file. So here is what I found, for the following code, nothing gets written to the file, which I think is because an open file handler is not shared across processes.

```
import multiprocessing
import sys
import datetime
import time


def worker(fd, index):
  fd.write("worker %d %s\n" % (index, datetime.datetime.now()))
  time.sleep(5 - index)
  fd.write("worker %d again %s\n" % (index, datetime.datetime.now()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  fd = open(sys.argv[1], "w")
  threads = list()
  for i in xrange(5):
    th = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(fd, i,))
    threads.append(th)
    th.start()

  for each in threads:
    each.join()

  fd.close()
```

while the following code works fine because of shared memory between threads.

```
import threading
import sys
import datetime


def worker(fd, index):
  fd.write("worker %d %s\n" % (index, datetime.datetime.now()))
  time.sleep(5 - index)
  fd.write("worker %d again %s\n" % (index, datetime.datetime.now()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  fd = open(sys.argv[1], "w")
  threads = list()
  for i in xrange(5):
    th = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(fd, i,))
    threads.append(th)
    th.start()

  for each in threads:
    each.join()

  fd.close()
```

I wanted to use multiple process instead of threads to write to the same file, so I implemented the following. I assumed that I might have to use locks to restrict access to the file by different processes, however the following seems to work fine without it.

```
import multiprocessing
import sys
import datetime
import time


def write_to_file(text, file_name):
  fd = open(file_name, "a")
  fd.write(text)
  fd.close()


def worker(file_name, index):
  while True:
    write_to_file("worker %d %s\n" % (index, datetime.datetime.now()), file_name)
    time.sleep(5 - index)
    write_to_file("worker %d %s again\n" % (index, datetime.datetime.now()), file_name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  file_name = sys.argv[1]
  fd = open(file_name, 'w')
  fd.write("test input\n")
  fd.close()
  jobs = []
  for i in xrange(5):
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(file_name, i,))
    process.start()
    jobs.append(process)

  for j in jobs:
    j.join()
```

My doubt is around this. Is the "open" call here blocking and already protected or do I need to implement locking around a call to "write_to_file"? In essence, will an "open" call block for one process while the file is being written to by another process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to co-ordinate writes from multiple processes to a file which is concurrently opened among them, through locking, possibly entailing range locking, possibly entailing *fsync()* and *seek()* ... while this is possible under most operating systems and under some conditions ... it’s also likely to be error prone, unreliable, and subject to some odd corner cases (especially for files shared across a network such as NFS or SMB).

I would suggest that this is a perfect case for using the ***multiprocessing.Queue*** class. Have on process act as the consumer, writing to the file, and have all the others acting as producers writing to the Queue rather than to the file.  This will likely outperform any locking strategy you try to cobble together for yourself and it’s almost certain to be far more more robust.